# PHP Variable inside <Script> with \

Tags: php, variables, analytics

Hey so I'm trying to add a variable inside this code, I need to replace the bold with my variable.

```
    $_url_form .= '</form></div>';
    $_url_form.= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    $_url_form.= "var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ?    \"https://ssl.\" : \"http://www.\");";
    $_url_form.= "document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\" + gaJsHost + \"google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));";
    $_url_form.= "</script>";
    $_url_form.= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    $_url_form.= "var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(\"**UA-46575117-1**\");";
    $_url_form.= "pageTracker._initData();";
    $_url_form.= "pageTracker._trackPageview();";
    $_url_form.= "</script>";

    $_response_body = preg_replace('#\<\s*body(.*?)\>#si', "$0\n$_url_form" , $_response_body, 1);
```

when I place my variable inplace of the bold above it renders out this:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker ("<?php  echo UA-46575117-1; ?>")
```

Guessing it has something to do with the \ \ \ being used.

any input apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
$_url_form .= "var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(\"$myVariable\");";
```

Comment: wow so that totally works! so there was no need for the <?php echo $variable ?>  ?

Comment: Nope... not inside a double-quoted string. And please, don't use the heredoc syntax. It's unsightly in pretty much any language (editorial).

Comment: Cheers dude! marking you as the answer solved my issue! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the php heredoc syntax. Google if you're not familiar with it.